# lmfit: parameters to follow a Gaussian distribution have to be integer

Tags: python, lmfit

I tried to fit two Gaussian peaks, whose parameters are floating point data.
but the following error occurred.Must the Gaussian parameters in lmfit be integer data?

> File "E:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\lmfit-1.0.1-py3.7.egg\lmfit\lineshapes.py", line 31, in gaussian
> * exp(-(1.0*x-center)**2 / max(tiny, (2*sigma**2))))
> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

and this is the code:

```
exp_mod = ExponentialModel(prefix='exp_')
pars = exp_mod.guess(y, x=x)

gauss1 = GaussianModel(prefix='g1_')
pars.update(gauss1.make_params())

pars['g1_center'].set(value=param_1[1], min=param_1[1]-0.2, max=param_1[1]+0.2)
pars['g1_sigma'].set(value=param_1[2], min=0.1)
pars['g1_amplitude'].set(value=param_1[0], min=0)
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. On line 31 you are trying to multiply two vars of different type.

Comment: line 31 is the function defined by the lmfit library, Can I make any changes? And I cannot find this error.

Comment: The edit button is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64801883/edit). And please insert the error message as text, [not as an image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Answer (score 0):

All the parameter values in lmfit are floating-point values ('float').  The data should be in numpy arrays of type 'float' as well.  I would guess that your `x` or `y` data are not in numpy arrays.

But that is a guess: without a complete example, it's more or less impossible to tell what might be going wrong.